# Why is my code to rotate a needle image moving the position of the needle under Brownian motion? Why do images at origin show up scattered?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, transform

At http://ancient-clock.stornge.com, I have what is intended to be pseudo-Brownian motion on the angle of a dial's needle, with each iteration moving the clock one degree clockwise, one degree counterclockwise, or not move this instant. It should be doing a fractal "staggering drunk."

Note that if you load the page, the "staggering drunk"/"random walk" image starts offscreen, but usually staggers on screen.

That's issue 1. Issue 2 is that the parts of the diagram are all set at (0, 0) and I call ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); to get a fresh start, but the hands are still showing up scattered.

The code is:

```
        var ANCIENT_CLOCK = {};
        ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle = 45;
        ANCIENT_CLOCK.draw_clock = function()
            {
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(100, 100);
            var height_ratio = ANCIENT_CLOCK.clock_face.height /
              jQuery(window).height();
            var width_ratio = ANCIENT_CLOCK.clock_face.width /
              jQuery(window).width();
            var ratio = null;
            if (height_ratio < width_ratio)
                {
                ratio = width_ratio;
                }
            else
                {
                ratio = height_ratio;
                }
            ratio = Math.max(1, 1 / ratio);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.scale(ratio, ratio);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.rendered_time = new Date();
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.drawImage(ANCIENT_CLOCK.clock_face, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.hour_angle = ((ANCIENT_CLOCK.rendered_time
              .getTime() % (86400 * 1000 / 24)) / (( 86400 * 1000 / 24) * Math.PI));

            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(100, 100);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.rotate(2 * Math.PI * ANCIENT_CLOCK.hour_angle);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.drawImage(ANCIENT_CLOCK.hour_hand, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.minute_angle = ((ANCIENT_CLOCK.rendered_time
              .getTime() % (86400 * 1000 * 60)) /
              (86400 * 1000 * 60));

            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.rotate(2 * Math.PI *
              ANCIENT_CLOCK.minute_angle);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.drawImage(ANCIENT_CLOCK.minute_hand, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.second_angle = (ANCIENT_CLOCK.rendered_time
              .getTime() % 86400 * 1000 * 3600) / (86400 * 1000 * 3600);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.drawImage(ANCIENT_CLOCK.second_hand, 1000, 300);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            if (ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle < 1)
                {
                if (Math.random() < .5)
                    {
                    ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle += 1;
                    }
                }
            else if (ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle > 90)
                {
                if (Math.random() > .5)
                    {
                    ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle -= 1;
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                if (Math.random() < 1 / 3)
                    {
                    ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle += 1;
                    }
                else if (Math.random() < .5)
                    {
                    ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle -= 1;
                    }
                }
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.translate(0, 0);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.rotate((ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_angle / 90) *
              (Math.PI / 4) + Math.PI / 8);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.drawImage(ANCIENT_CLOCK.dial_hand, 100,
              100);
            ANCIENT_CLOCK.context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this particular question, you might organize and simplify your code with a function:

Organizing into a function has the benefit that you only need to look 1 place for errors / improvements.

**Create a function that draws any clock hand at a particular angle**, like this:

- Take in 2 arguments: (1) an image of a clock hand and (2) an angle at which to draw that hand.
- context.save() to save the current state of your canvas.
- Translate to the center of your clock hands.
- Rotate based on the given angle.
- Draw the supplied image.
- context.restore() to restore the canvas to it’s un-translated & un-rotated state.

Notice that the `context.save` + `context.restore` are used so you don’t have to worry about using identity transforms or un-transforming your canvas after transform operations.

With your code organized and simplified, you can attack your Brownian sweep in a more direct manor that let’s you concentrate on sweeps instead of transforms.

Since you are working with time, a function that takes in minutes/seconds and converts to radian degrees is useful.  Here is such a function:

```
function secondsToRadians(seconds) {
    var degrees=(seconds-15)*6;
    var radians=(degrees * Math.PI)/180;
    return(radians);
}
```

Moral of the story…

If you find yourself typing the same thing more than a few times, **put it in a function**.

It seems that you are stuck on this particular 100 lines of code--- you've asked 5 questions on this same code!

Please (PLEASE!) check out this useful set of tutorials that covers the problems you’ve been facing in your clock project.

You deserve to be armed with this information as you work on your clock project…

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial